# How can I limit a table to fit inside 90% of my web page and no more?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```html
<div style="display:table; width: 90%">
  <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;"><textarea>ABCDEFG</textarea></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"><textarea>HIJKLMN</textarea></div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;"><textarea>ABCDEFG</textarea></div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;"><textarea>HIJKLMN</textarea></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the `textarea`s are small then it fits inside the 90%. But when I increase the size of the `textarea`s by dragging them it goes beyond the 90% of my browser window and a scroll bar appears at the bottom.

Is there a way that I can limit this so it does a maximum of 90% and won't extend any more without using any library but with using any CSS that can be coded for a modern browser.

Comment: use `width: 90vw;`

Comment: have you tried adding `table-layout: fixed;` on the div which has `display: table;` ?

Comment: you can use `resize: vertical;` for your `textarea` too, thus it will only be resize-able vertically not horizontally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `max-width` will stop the table immediately resizing however if the textareas are resized enough then the table can still extend beyond it's 90% maximum, you can stop this behavior by also setting a `max-width` for the text areas themselves

```
<div style="display:table; width: 90%; max-width: 90%">
    <div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="display: table-cell;"><textarea style="max-width: 45vh;">ABCDEFG</textarea></div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;"><textarea style="max-width: 45vh;">HIJKLMN</textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="display: table-cell;"><textarea style="max-width: 45vh;">ABCDEFG</textarea></div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;"><textarea style="max-width: 45vh;">HIJKLMN</textarea></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This isn't the most graceful fix with it's inline styles and it's use of `vw` (viewport width) units, but it should allow you to limit the sizes for what you need to do, then tweak it further

Answer (score 2):

```
max-width:90%
```

or add css code to disable resizing the textarea element

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```